# Why call a Contract an "Agreement"?

Tags: contract-law

[In my personal contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/57710), just "Agreement" appears, never "Contract". For another example, see p 62 in *Lessons for Baby Sharks: The Essential Guide to Thriving as a New Lawyer* (2016 2 ed.) by Grover E. Cleveland [BA English (Washington University in St. Louis), JD Magna Cum Laude (Saint Louis University School of Law)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/grovercleveland/).

[image]

As you lawyers definitely know, Agreement ≠ Contract. An Agreement is merely one of five necessary conditions for forming a Contract.

> A party who wishes to establish that a legally binding contract has been formed between
> himself and another party must prove a number of matters. The first is that the parties
> have reached agreement. This is usually done by demonstrating that one party has made an
> offer that the other has accepted. The rules relating to offer and acceptance are discussed in
> Chapter 3. Secondly, the agreement must be expressed in a form that is sufficiently certain for
> the court to be able to enforce. The tests applied by the courts when deciding whether a term
> has been expressed in a form that is too vague, incomplete, or uncertain to be enforced are

> discussed in Chapter 4. Thirdly, the agreement must be supported by consideration (although
> it is possible that effect may be given to a promise that is unsupported by consideration via an
> estoppel). The doctrine of consideration and the role that estoppel can play in giving effect to
> promises that are unsupported by consideration are discussed in Chapter 5. Fourthly, the law
> may only recognize the validity of the agreement if it is entered into in a particular form (such
> as writing). The significance of requirements of form has diminished in recent years but they
> have not been entirely abolished. Requirements of form are discussed in Chapter 6. Finally [5],
> the parties must have had an intention to create legal relations. This intention is presumed in
> commercial transactions, but in the case of domestic and social agreements the law initially
> presumes that the parties did not intend to be legally bound by their agreement. The doctrine
> of intention to create legal relations is discussed in Chapter 7.

McKendrick, *Contract Law Text, Cases, and Material*s 9th Edition, 2020, pp 17-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A contract is an agreement that is enforcable by law

All contracts are agreements; not all agreements are contracts.

- An agreement between a construction company and a government to build 45km of motorway is also a contract. If the construction company fails to build it or the government fails to pay legal consequences will follow.
- An agreement for you and I to meet for drinks after work is not a contract. If I stand you up, legal consequences will not follow (relationship consequences probably will).

Answer (score 1):

An agreement is not necessarily a contract, but a contract is always an agreement. As coffee is a drink, you can call it a drink.